# Неверный POST запрос

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

Angular + Spring MVC.
Собираю данные из формы с ангуляра

```
<form ng-submit="updateSalary()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class = "container row">
    <h1>Edit salary</h1>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img ng-src="/image?id={{salary.data.id}}" width="366px" height="488px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <table class = "table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td> Team Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" required="string" ng-model="salary.data.team_name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Player Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" required="string" ng-model="salary.data.player_name" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Salary: </td>
            <td><input type="number" required="string" ng-model="salary.data.salary"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Position: </td>
            <td><input type="text" required="string" ng-model="salary.data.position"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sex: </td>
            <td><input type="text" required="string" ng-model="salary.data.sex" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Living Place: </td>
            <td><input type="text" required="string" ng-model="salary.data.living_place"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Load new foto: </td>
            <td><input type="file" file-model="myFile"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/" role="button">Cancel</a>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

И при отправке получаю, что

> "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Мои контроллеры:

```
Salary.service('fileUpload', ['$http', '$location', function ($http, $location) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(data,  uploadUrl){

    $http.post(uploadUrl, data, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type' : undefined}
    })
        .success(function(){
            $location.path("/");
        })
        .error(function(){
            alert('Загрузка не прошла!');
        });
}
}]);

Salary.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);


Salary.controller("editSalaryController", [ '$scope', '$http', 'salary', '$location', 'fileUpload',
function($scope, $http, salary, $location, fileUpload){

    $scope.salary = salary;

    var dataForm = new FormData();
    dataForm.append('id', $scope.salary.data.id);
    dataForm.append('team_name', $scope.salary.data.team_name);
    dataForm.append('player_name', $scope.salary.data.player_name);
    dataForm.append('salary', $scope.salary.data.salary);
    dataForm.append('position', $scope.salary.data.position);
    dataForm.append('sex', $scope.salary.data.sex);
    dataForm.append('living_place', $scope.salary.data.living_place);
    dataForm.append('image', $scope.myFile);
    var url = "/editSalary"
    $scope.updateSalary = function() {
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(dataForm, url);
    }}]);


@RequestMapping(value = "/editSalary", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
@ResponseBody
public Salary editSalary(@RequestBody FileUpload dataForm){

    Salary salary = new Salary();

    try{
        salary.setId(dataForm.getId());
        salary.setTeam_name(dataForm.getTeam_name());
        salary.setPlayer_name(dataForm.getPlayer_name());
        salary.setSalary(dataForm.getSalary());
        salary.setPosition(dataForm.getPosition());
        salary.setSex(dataForm.getSex());
        salary.setLiving_place(dataForm.getLiving_place());
        salary.setImage(dataForm.getImage().getBytes());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    this.salaryService.updateToDB(salary);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Настройте на сервере журналирование уровня DEBUG. После этого контроллер выведет в журнал понятное описание того, что именно ему "не понравилось" в вашем запросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я разобрался, и хотел бы поделиться опытом в этом вопросе.
Когда мы используем @RequestBody для отправки post-запроса, мы этим обозначаем что все наше тело запроса находится тут. Но в моем случае, сам Spring не мог сериализовать тело в класс. В этом случае необходимо использовать @RequestParam и каждый аргумент разбивать отдельно. Сделав так, я обозначил отдельно каждый.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addSalary", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Salary addSalary(@RequestParam(value = "image", required = false) MultipartFile image,
                        @RequestParam("player_name") String player_name,
                        @RequestParam("team_name") String team_name,
                        @RequestParam("salary") Integer salary,
                        @RequestParam("position") String position,
                        @RequestParam("sex") String sex,
                        @RequestParam("living_place") String living_place)
```